# Как правильно обновить данные

Tags: c#, ado.net

Создал глобальное соединение с БД. Далее пытаюсь добавить данные:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO [Table] ([User], [Message], [DataTime]) VALUES (USER,  @Message, GETDATE())";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, сonnection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", sMessage);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Вот пример зачитки с базы:

```
    public List<TMessage> StrIEnumReturn()
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [Table] where id>" + i.ToString() + "", сonnection);
        SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<TMessage> sMess = new List<TMessage>();
        if (myReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                sMess.Add(new TMessage { Id = myReader.GetInt32(0), sUser = myReader.GetString(1), sMessage = myReader.GetString(2), dtTime = myReader.GetDateTime(3) });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        myReader.Close();

        return sMess;
    }
```

Все работает, данные добавляются. Но проблема в том, что после добавления они не отображаются (не перечитываются с БД). Разрываю соединение и заново соединяюсь с БД, данные появляются. Можно ли реализовать это без разрыва соединения?

Comment: Где именно они у вас не отображаются? Приведенный вами код вставляет данные в БД, но не занимается отображением новых данных в приложении.

Comment: У меня API, вот код, который зачитывает данные из базы для отображения:

Comment: "Создал глобальное соединение с БД" - уже интересно.

Comment: У меня API, вот код, который зачитывает данные из базы для отображения:

Comment: @Сергей не мучайтесь с комментариями, добавьте код в вопрос - линк "править" под вопросом.

Comment: Спасибо. Фактически вопрос такой: При глобальном соединении и добавленных данных, как прочитать эти данные в этом же соединении?

Comment: Или как-то по другому нужно сделать, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

В SQL Server -е принято разрывать соединение после каждого действия, и соединяться заново. Так как число соединений ограничено. Следовательно нужно каждый раз открывать и разрывать соединение. Извините за беспокойство...

Comment: тип приложения: WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, ...?

Comment: По порядку: SQL Server, Web API, Xamarin

Comment: Web API, то есть возможна параллельная обработка запросов? Как это сочетается с глобальным `SqlConnection`-ом?

Comment: Об этом я не подумал, спасибо что подсказали...